# Regex expression to extract strings

Tags: regex, email, expression, regex-greedy

I have the following expression:

**MN=Abc123,MN=sssa,MN=abc adsa 1,MN=&3ams d'amé,MN=dat,CB=ds,CB=ds**

How can I extract one by one the expressions following **MN=** ?
eg: firstly I want to extract *Abc123*, secondly I wnat *sssa* and so on ...

Appreciate your answer!

Comment: Any particular programming language are you using for regex? python, java, JavaScript etc?

Comment: Where are you using regex? Any particular editor?

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture group:

```
"[A-Z]{2}=([^,]+)"
```

Then get the first group form your matched object.

Or if the language you are dealing for supports the look-around you can use a positive look-behind in order to directly match the expected parts:

```
"(?<=[A-Z]{2}=)[^,]+"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kasramvd!
From what I can see it doesn't support lookbehind ...To be honest I don't know what that means actually.

The capture group seem to work. It removes the MN=, but it still keeps the CB=...

Comment: Also, it removes all OU=, but I want to extract each part of the expression:

Comment: How can I do that?
1st I want to have Abc123, then I want sssa and so on..
How can I do that. I think I need to use something like $1, but I'm not familiar with this...

Answer (score 0):

If your regex environment supports lookbehind, you can extract desired information with this regex:

> Environment supporting Lookbehind

```
(?<=MN=)(.*?)(?=,)
```

> Environment not supporting Lookbehind

```
(?:MN=)(.*?)(?=,)
```

Your desired result will be stored in Group 1, aka `$1`

Based on your input string, here is result

```
Abc123
sssa
abc adsa 1
&3ams d'amé
dat
```

See live demo [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3AMN%3D)(.*%3F)(%3F%3D%2C)&i=MN%3DAbc123%2CMN%3Dsssa%2CMN%3Dabc%20adsa%201%2CMN%3D%263ams%20d%27am%C3%A9%2CMN%3Ddat%2CCB%3Dds%2CCB%3Dds)

Comment: Thanks Saleem for your input.
It doesn't seem to support lookbehind.

I need to divide the expression and then extract each part using something like $1 ...I'm not so familiar with regex unfortunately :(

Comment: It's ok, check out updated version. But unless you mention your programming language or particular text editor, it's difficult to suggest a proper variant of regex.